# Count the number of points within a specific distance of each raster cell with a timestamp condition

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, r-sf

I have thousands of coordinates for point data (sample in code below) that are derived from a tractor guidance system with a timestamp for each coordinate. I created a 1 m resolution empty raster. How can I count the number of points within a specified distance (let's say 14 meters) for each raster cell but only for points **not within** 6 (+/- 3) timestamp  units of the point?

```
libs <- c("raster","dplyr", "rgdal", "sp", "sf")
have   <- libs %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if(any(!have)) install.packages(libs[!have])
sapply(libs, function(i) require(i, character.only=TRUE))

pts70 <- structure(list(Latitude = c(35.09263063, 35.09263784, 35.09264402, 
35.09265182, 35.09265815, 35.09266566, 35.09267184, 35.09267979, 
35.09269097, 35.09269627, 35.09270054, 35.09270422, 35.09271511, 
35.09272232, 35.09272997, 35.09273821, 35.09273468, 35.09274645, 
35.09277486, 35.09280812, 35.09284226, 35.09287464, 35.09290098, 
35.0929129, 35.09291143, 35.09289568, 35.09287273, 35.09285683, 
35.09285477, 35.09287331, 35.09290672, 35.09294866, 35.09298825, 
35.09301548, 35.09301769, 35.09301077, 35.09299223, 35.09296839, 
35.09294557, 35.09292924, 35.09291894, 35.09290893, 35.09289936, 
35.09289112, 35.09288273, 35.0928742, 35.09286654, 35.09285771, 
35.09285168, 35.09284314, 35.09283593, 35.0928271, 35.09282092, 
35.09281209, 35.09280444, 35.09279826, 35.09278899, 35.09278148, 
35.0927728, 35.09276544, 35.09275764, 35.09275146, 35.09274219, 
35.0927363, 35.09272747, 35.09271967, 35.09271069, 35.09270378, 
35.0926948, 35.09268847, 35.09268038), Longitude = c(-93.98941262, 
-93.98937898, -93.98934607, -93.98931225, -93.9892779, -93.98924354, 
-93.98921387, -93.98918347, -93.9891466, -93.98910901, -93.98907951, 
-93.98904479, -93.98900594, -93.98897033, -93.98893741, -93.9889027, 
-93.98885612, -93.98880917, -93.98880414, -93.98880971, -93.98880432, 
-93.98878651, -93.98875773, -93.9887214, -93.98868668, -93.98865611, 
-93.98862265, -93.98858002, -93.98853092, -93.98848326, -93.98845088, 
-93.98844207, -93.98845808, -93.98849369, -93.9885329, -93.98856977, 
-93.98859603, -93.98861744, -93.98864136, -93.9886714, -93.98870395, 
-93.98873669, -93.98876906, -93.98880216, -93.98883651, -93.98887015, 
-93.98890414, -93.98893849, -93.98897069, -93.98900486, -93.98903922, 
-93.98907357, -93.98910811, -93.98913958, -93.98917268, -93.98920577, 
-93.98923941, -93.98927196, -93.98930524, -93.98933833, -93.98937215, 
-93.98940344, -93.98943744, -93.98947125, -93.98950453, -93.98953834, 
-93.9895718, -93.98960579, -93.98963889, -93.98967288, -93.98970669
), Timestamp = c(1540321036L, 
1540321037L, 1540321038L, 1540321039L, 1540321040L, 1540321041L, 
1540321042L, 1540321043L, 1540321044L, 1540321045L, 1540321046L, 
1540321047L, 1540321049L, 1540321050L, 1540321051L, 1540321052L, 
1540321053L, 1540321054L, 1540321055L, 1540321056L, 1540321057L, 
1540321058L, 1540321059L, 1540321060L, 1540321061L, 1540321062L, 
1540321063L, 1540321064L, 1540321065L, 1540321066L, 1540321067L, 
1540321068L, 1540321069L, 1540321070L, 1540321071L, 1540321072L, 
1540321073L, 1540321074L, 1540321075L, 1540321076L, 1540321077L, 
1540321078L, 1540321079L, 1540321080L, 1540321081L, 1540321082L, 
1540321083L, 1540321084L, 1540321085L, 1540321086L, 1540321087L, 
1540321088L, 1540321089L, 1540321090L, 1540321091L, 1540321092L, 
1540321093L, 1540321094L, 1540321095L, 1540321096L, 1540321097L, 
1540321098L, 1540321099L, 1540321100L, 1540321101L, 1540321102L, 
1540321103L, 1540321104L, 1540321105L, 1540321106L, 1540321107L
)), row.names = 3371:3441, class = "data.frame")

sf_pts <- pts70 %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), agr="constant") %>%
  sf::st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = 32615)

r <- raster()
bb <- extent(sf_pts)
r <- setExtent(r, bb)
res(r) <- 1
crs(r) <- '+init=EPSG:32615'
```

Comment: @42-I added the point and line buffers, as well as library code. I could not figure out how to count the number of points/lines within 7 meters for the raster object, so excluded here.

Comment: Strange, I just ran this in a vanilla environment and no error. Running R 3.5.1 in Windows 7 pro. Sorry my variable name was confusing for you, but should run fine with copy/paste into an R script.

Comment: Package access was fine. My R version (running in Linux) is also 3.5.1 and all of my packages were installed in the last week.  raster ;  dplyr ;  rgdal  ;    sp   ;   sf :  respectively: 
"2.8-4" "0.7.7" "1.3-6" "1.3-1" "0.7-1".   I've looked at the output but I'm having trouble figuring out the actual problem. Perhaps if you plotted what you are seeing and made reference to to specific locations?

Comment: @42-I tried to clarify the question; the answer to which will solve at least the first step in my overall problem.

Comment: When I change "EPSG" to "epsg" the warning goes away, and there is then valid entry in `r@crs@progargs`, but the added titles to the plots do not help me understand your problem. It's perfectly possible that my lack of experience with the specialized spatial data structures and terminology is the reason I still don't understand. If I were you, I would try posting the question in the spatial SIG mailing list. I would suggest further expanding your description of what you are trying to do. It still seems cryptic to me.

Comment: @42- I plan to post on the spatial SIG list as you mentioned, but I've given some thought to my problem and tried to be more precise with the description this time. Thanks for giving this some attention.

Comment: I would start by attempting to fill your raster just with adjacency counts, but with no time condition. Break up the task into smaller, less complicated tasks. Then add refinements.

Comment: I did a seaarch on "[r] raster adjacency" and came up with what sounds like an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361138/assign-rows-to-a-group-based-on-spatial-neighborhood-and-temporal-criteria-in-r